# Qt Version Incrementing

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I am using a batch file to increment the last version number. I set it up to a variable in the `.pro` file, then in my `main.cpp` I try setting a Qstring to a version number and then using QDebug to see if the number is right. So far the batch file is not being called and the last `args` when setting QString to the version number is "too few" with a warning message.

**The `.pro` file having the problems:**

```
VERSION_MAJOR = 1
VERSION_MINOR = 0
VERSION_BUILD = $$(autoincrement.bat)

VERSION = $${VERSION_MAJOR}.$${VERSION_MINOR}.$${VERSION_BUILD}

DEFINES += "VERSION_MAJOR=$$VERSION_MAJOR"\
       "VERSION_MINOR=$$VERSION_MINOR"\
       "VERSION_BUILD=$${VERSION_BUILD}"
```

**`main.cpp`**

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QString version = QString("%1.%2.%3").arg(VERSION_MAJOR)
            .arg(VERSION_MINOR).arg(VERSION_BUILD);
    QApplication::setApplicationVersion(version);
    qDebug() << version;
    NewsBulletin w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: `$$(autoincrement.bat)` attempts to access an env. var merely, iirc ($${} would means a plain var), so you need to run the .bat with other means, essentially (I'd search for "qmake pre-build" smth)

Comment: @mlvljr I would like to make VERSION_BUILD set to the number though Edit: Would placing the version in a header file make any difference compared to the actually .pro file?

Comment: Only if you know what it is beforehand, I guess...
I may be wrong on the .bat not being invoked, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417061/automatic-increment-of-build-number-in-qt-creator

Comment: @mlvljr, one other question, by placing the version variables in a header, and them being "#define VERSION_BUILD 1" etc what type of variable would they then be? Or how could I declare it as a variable? edit: I attempted to use that post and got terrible results from running the batch and settings as a variable, possibly due to version differences since I am using Qt 5.5.

Comment: @mlvljr I solved that issue, not sure if it was the right way. I set the constants into local integers then turned it into QString, or whatever I desired.

Comment: The type will be whatever you choose for a var that gets the number, say, simplest way would be using `int versionBuild = VERSION_BUILD;` (or something like that); for strings, there are tricks with quoting, like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3959495/110118

Comment: Beware of cruel mods, btw ;)
(these ppl don't like simple / duplicate looking questions)

Comment: @mlvljr, yeah I understand that it is similar to older questions, but they are from 5+ major releases ago making them outdated. I had to run the batch file in the end by a complete different method since I never could get it to run inside the .pro file. Anyways thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution to iterating for each build for Windows (definitely prefer Bash):

1. Create a `version.bat` containing:

   ```
   @echo off 
   set /p var= <version.txt 
   set /a var= %var%+1 
   echo %var% >version.txt
   break >version.h
   echo #define VERSION_MAJOR 1 >version.h
   echo #define VERSION_MINOR 0 >>version.h
   echo #define VERSION_BUILD %var% >>version.h
   echo %var%
   ```

   Run it once to create the other files.
2. Next, go to projects in `qt` and add a build step to debug and run.
3. Put the batch file in the command, and go to the `.pro` folder where the batch is in the working directory.
4. Next, add the `version.h` file to the project.
5. Finally, you have to include `version.h` in each file you want to use the version numbers.

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost, the qmake syntax for calling an external program is

```
VARIABLE=$$system(autoincrement.bat)
```

what you're doing instead is getting the value of an environment variable called `autoincrement.bat`.

Second, your code will still have the problem that

- unless the `pro` file changes, qmake will not be automatically ran on it
- unless the source files also change, they will not get rebuilt

Therefore, this way it's very very hard to actually do a version bump and recompile the code. qmake, unlike other build systems, doesn't support this kind of "special" variables which change and cause dependent code to require a recompilation. Your second approach (generating a version.h file) is definitely better.